# execute a command on every file that has an specific extension

Tags: bash, loops, nested, find

as simple as the title. I have nested files and i want to execute a command on them if they end in `.toml`.

Trying with

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '3i value = 1' {} \;
```

runs over every file, but is there a way to do it over only the files ending in `.toml`?

Answer (score 3):

There sure is; use the `-name` switch:

```
find . -name '*.toml' -type f -exec sed -i '3i value = 1' {} \;
```

This matches any file ending in `.toml`. Careful to include the quotes to prevent the `*` from being expanded by the shell - you want it to be passed to `find` as-is.

By the way, you can speed up the execution of your script by using `-exec {} +` instead:

```
find . -name '*.toml' -type f -exec sed -i '3i value = 1' {} +
```

This passes multiple results to the same instance of `sed`, rather than spawning a separate one for every result.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name '*.toml' -exec sed -i '3i value = 1' {} \;
```

Comment: Didn't know it was that easy!